# Comparing user input with text file (reading text file)

Tags: java, user-input

Im having trouble getting the program to read the info in a text file and compare it to user input. If the input and text match a menu will then be displayed if not the user will be locked out. I heard of a buffer line, but I'm not sure how it works. Any help will be appreciated!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class test123{
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException  {
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter correct credentials to log in");
    System.out.println("Username: ");
    System.out.println("Password: ");
    String userName = sc1.nextLine();
    String passWord = sc1.nextLine();

    File inFile = new File ("employee.txt");



    while (sc1.hasNextLine())
    {          
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (inFile);
        String [] arrayName= new String [4];
         String uName = arrayName[0];
         String pWord = arrayName[1];   
         String line = sc.nextLine();
         line = sc.nextLine();

         if(userName.equals(uName) && passWord.equals(pWord)) 
         {
             System.out.println("Welcome " + userName + "!");
             System.out.println("Menu: ");
             System.out.println("\t1) Account");
             System.out.println("\t2) Payroll");
             System.out.println("\t3) Attendance Report");
             System.out.println("\t4) Service Desk");
         }
         }
}
```

}

Comment: String [] arrayName= new String [4];
String uName = arrayName[0];
String pWord = arrayName[1];   
Would have no impact, as arrayName contains all null!? This code has lot of mistakes I think!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Scanner sc = new Scanner(inFile);` should be outside your while loop.

Also check out this resource : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are checking if a user's username and password is correct or not!. This might work

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException  {
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter correct credentials to log in");
    System.out.println("Username: ");
    System.out.println("Password: ");
    String userName = sc1.nextLine();
    String passWord = sc1.nextLine();

    File inFile = new File ("employee.txt");


    Scanner sc = new Scanner (inFile);
    String uName = sc.nextLine();
    String pWord = sc.nextLine();   

    sc.close();
    if(userName.equals(uName) && passWord.equals(pWord)) 
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome " + userName + "!");
        System.out.println("Menu: ");
        System.out.println("\t1) Account");
        System.out.println("\t2) Payroll");
        System.out.println("\t3) Attendance Report");
        System.out.println("\t4) Service Desk");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Error.!");
    }

    }
```

Well if you had empty lines in file or no text in file etc., this will not work as expected.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I figured it out last night but I kept receiving an error so I tried your idea this morning and I got the same error. I don't know what is means by this. It reads Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1150)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1573)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at test123.main(test123.java:32)

Comment: You should not close the scanner until you have read all what you want. The scanner object was closed before line number 32.